# how to ignore incorrect types and continue json deserialization using swift codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I was wondering if there is an easy way to deal with the case where the type defined in my class does not match what I receive from the back-end. Documentation is scarce, so among the hundreds of parameters I've parsed I worry that there will be an error somewhere.

```
class Data : Codable {
   var Validation: Bool?
   var otherParam: String

}
```

For example, if validation is actually a string instead of a boolean, then parsing seems to just stop and fail with the default decoding.

My initial instinct is to override the decoding and use an optional try on each key. Is that the right idea?

Comment: Do you mean that Validation will sometimes be a String and sometimes a Bool? Then yeah, you should implement the decoding method yourself.

Comment: Usually backends are sending consistent data. Optionals don't ignore type mismatch errors so figure out the proper type. JSON is pretty easy to read and `DecodingError`s are extremely descriptive. And don't name a custom class `Data`. This can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Basically go analyze the .net code since there is no documentation or use of nswag/swashbuckle

Comment: Use something like https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift to create the data model for you.

Comment: that's very neat, but my biggest problem is that many json fields in the response are null. So until it comes across a piece of data where the type is not null, I cannot determine the type of the data properly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to do this. Type mismatches are fatal errors, and the whole thing will explode. You can do it by hand, but for your case that's likely extremely tedious. Just to show how to do it, though:

```
struct Data : Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case validation, otherParam
    }
    var validation: Bool?
    var otherParam: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.validation = try? container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .validation)
        self.otherParam = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .otherParam) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Obviously this is very tedious, but look at [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) which may be able to generate the code you need.

Another approach is to decode into arbitrary JSON, and then extract what you need.  For example, see [RNJSON](https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON/blob/main/Sources/RNJSON/RNJSON.swift), which allows you to parse any legal JSON, and then query it.

(I'm currently hacking around on a new decoder that would handle this kind of situation, but it's a pretty difficult problem. There's no simple switch you can throw, because in a deeply nested structure, it's not obvious at what to do at each level. For example, since `otherParam` isn't Optional, what should it be set to if it's not a String? Should the whole Data type fail, or do you need to define a default like `""` to assign? What if `otherParam` were a Bool? Is the default true or false? Swift avoids implicit defaults. But still, this is a real problem, and interesting enough that I'm hacking on a toy to explore it. In the end, I suspect for this particular case it won't be any better than hand-writing the `init`.)